# How to use foreach loop using two array to get result

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have two array as follow

```
[1]=>Array(
    [ingrediant]=>Array(
        [A]=>Chicken [C]=>TomatoJuice
        )
    [price]=> 100
    )
[2]=>Array(
    [ingrediant]=>Array(
        [A]=>Pork  [C]=>LimeJuice
        )
    [price]=> 50
    )
[3]=>Array(
    [ingrediant]=>Array(
        [B]=>Chille [C]=>TomatoJuice
    )
    [price]=>100

    )
)
```

And

```
Array([A]=>Array([name]=>meat [code]=>001)
       [B]=>Array([name]=>Vegetable [code]=>002)
       [C]=>Array([name]=>Juice [code]=>003)
)
```

First Array Show the food combo and Second Array Show Type of the Ingredients
For example,

> Chicken+tomatojuice Combo

Chicken is meat and tomatojuice is juice.
I would like to get the result as follow group by juice.

```
>Tomatojuice 
-Meat:Chicken, price:100
-Vegetable:Chille, price:100
>LimeJuice
-Meat:Pork, price:100
```

How can I get these results by using php foreach. I have tried several time.Not Okay at all.

Comment: Could you use SQL to get the actual results you desire?

Comment: I have tried again and again with several way i really can't get the way. I can get all the combo but don't know how to categorize.

Comment: they are completely two array !_!. That is why i can't get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should solve your problem

Based on your array declaration :

```
$food_combo[] = array(
    'ingrediant'=> array(
        'A' => 'Chicken',
        'C' => 'TomatoJuice'
        ),
    'price'=>100
);
$food_combo[] = array(
    'ingrediant'=> array(
        'A' => 'Pork',
        'C' => 'LimeJuice'
        ),
    'price'=>50
);
$food_combo[] = array(
    'ingrediant'=> array(
        'B' => 'Chille',
        'C' => 'TomatoJuice'
        ),
    'price'=>100
);
$types['A'] = array('name'=>'meat','code'=>'001');
$types['B'] = array('name'=>'vegetable','code'=>'002');
$types['C'] = array('name'=>'juice','code'=>'003');
```

Here is the algorithmic :

```
$group_by = 'C';
$combo = $output = array();

foreach($food_combo as $food){

    //array("A","B"....);
    $missed = array_diff(
        array_keys($food['ingrediant']), 
        isset($combo[$food['ingrediant'][$group_by]]) ? 
            $combo[$food['ingrediant'][$group_by]] : array()
    );

    if(count($missed)){
        //remove initial group define as key
        foreach(array_diff($missed,array($group_by)) as $type_code)
        $output[$food['ingrediant'][$group_by]][] =
            $types[$type_code]['name'] . 
            ':' . $food['ingrediant'][$type_code] . 
            ',' . 'price:' . $food['price'];
    }
}
print_r($output);
```